# How does a ranged voltage battery charger work?

Tags: charger

I'm wondering how a battery charger works that can take different voltages. For example Panasonic EY0L81 with voltage range frlm 10.8 - 28.8v, how does it identify which voltage to charge?. I also have a Bosch AL 1404 7.2 - 14.4v.

Comment: Most likely is the charger requesting charging voltage and current from the battery. Most secondary batteries are equipped with a protective circuit, which is also capable of communicating with the outside world

Comment: Does the inserted battery range have exactly the same mechanical profile? Are there contacts used for some batteries that are different when other batteries are inserted? Have you looked into this?

Comment: What chemistry? For NiCd and NiMH you can supply a voltage high enough and just limit the current to C/10 and be done with it. For higher currents, thermal cutoff with temperature sensor within the pack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a proprietary Panasonic "universal charger" for a set of Panasonic-specific cordless power tools. In addition to power leads, the batteries have a 8-pin connector for identification and something else:

[image]